# VS 2012 Add Shortcuts for "Disable all breakpoints" and "Enable all breakpoints"?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-debugging

How do I create short-cuts in visual studio 2012 for "Disable all breakpoints" and "Enable all breakpoints"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Tools -> Options -> Environment : Keyboard
```

Scroll down to `Debug.DisableAllBreakpoints`
Mark it as a global hotkey. And press a combo.

Rinse, Repeat for `Debug.EnableAllBreakpoints`