# Skip debug points - visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have a asp.net application. Some times I need to put many breakpoints. I know usage of <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd> to navigate between line of code. If I want to bypass all the breakpoints for time being but want to keep all breakpoints alive for future, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Debug->Windows->Breakpoints window, you may disable (by using checkbox) or delete any/all breakpoints [from there](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/04/27/enable-or-disable-all-breakpoints/). You may also configure custom VS shortcut for this [VS 2012 Add Shortcuts for "Disable all breakpoints" and "Enable all breakpoints"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456179/vs-2012-add-shortcuts-for-disable-all-breakpoints-and-enable-all-breakpoints).

Alternatively if you use local IIS you may run application without debugger attached, then if you want to start debugging use Debug->Attach to, select w3p.exe and start debugging (I use this setup often).